# Parse pushing data to detail view equals null

Tags: ios, object, uinavigationcontroller, parse-platform, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to push data to a detail view. I'm able to push to the new view but the object equals null.

ProfileDetailView.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *user;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *username;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bio;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
```

TableViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ProfileDetialView *controller = [[ProfileDetialView alloc]initWithNibName:@"ProfileDetialView" bundle:Nil];
    controller.user = object;
    //NSLog(@"%@",controller.user);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ShowDetails" sender: self];
    }
```

I've tried doing this multiple ways but ether it won't push to new view or it wont pass the object to the new view. It's probably something stupid as usually but any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `prepareForSegue`.

Assume `ShowDetails` segue goes to `ProfileDetailView` (and it is a controller) (am I right?).

you should add into **TableViewController**

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        ProfileDetailView *detailController = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailController.user = (PFObject *) sender;
    }
}
```

and change :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    PFObject *userObject = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ShowDetails" sender: userObject];
}
```

You code doesn't work, because you instantiate **NEW** detail controller, add data to it, but segue opens **ANOTHER** instance of detail controller (where you have no data).

Answer (score 1):

try into prepareForSegue method, and in the performSegue in sender object

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ShowDetails" sender: object];

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {

        ProfileDetialView *controller = (ProfileDetialView  *)segue.destinationViewController;

        PFObject *object = (PFObject *)sender;

        controller.user = object;

    }
}
```

hope it works for you